# Vim plugin/function to add annotations

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a function or plugin that would allow for easy adding annotations into the code.

Suppose user would have code like this and cursor on the position marked with a star:

```
class User

  *

end
```

Triggering a command it would prompt the user for the label (or in one step using the parameter, e.g. `:InsertLabel attributes`) and upon `<CR>` it would insert an annotation like following using some predefined formatting (could be set in `.vimrc` based on which character the language in the buffer uses for the comments) and keeping the indentation.

```
class User

  #######################
  # ATTRIBUTES
  #######################

end
```

Is there some plugin providing such a functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.